Session cookie is not being stored in browser, using next.js and custom server configuration
I am using Next.js on frontend, and using Express.js as backend, so I decided to connect express with next.js using custom server configuration of next.js, here is the basic setup:
on backend side, I got app.js:
const express = require('express')
//const proxy = require('express-http-proxy')
const parser = require('body-parser')
const session = require('express-session')
const dotenv = require('dotenv').config()
const {pool} = require('./routes/routes')

const pgSessionStore = require('connect-pg-simple')(session);


function nextAppWrapper(nextApp){

const app = express()
const port = 3000

const {router}  = require('./routes/routes')
const cors = require('cors')

const corsConfig = {
  methods:'*',
  origin:['http://127.0.0.1:8000','http://localhost:8000'],
  credentials:true
}


app.set('trust proxy', 1) // trust first proxy




app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})


app.use(cors(corsConfig))

app.use(session(
  {
  store: new pgSessionStore({
    pool:pool,
    tableName:'session',
    createTableIfMissing:true
    
  }),
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: true,
  cookie: { maxAge: 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,httpOnly: true , domain:'127.0.0.1:3000'},
  saveUninitialized: true,
}))




app.use(parser.urlencoded({extended:false}))
app.use(parser.json())
app.use('/api',router)
//app.use(proxy('http://127.0.0.1:3000'))

const handle = nextApp.getRequestHandler()

app.all('*', (req, res) => {
  return handle(req, res);
});


}

module.exports = nextAppWrapper




on frontend side (next), there is the server.ts file, this file need to be run when starting dev server:
const nextAppWrapper = require('../backend/app')
const next = require('next')


const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const nextApp = next({dev})
nextApp.prepare().then(()=>{
    nextAppWrapper(nextApp)

})

I am using MVC model in my backend, which means I have models functions, controllers functions and routes,
This is my code for login model to handle business logic:
Auth.login = async function ({email,password}){
    const checkEmail = await pool.query('SELECT email from _user WHERE email = $1',[email])
    

    if(checkEmail.rows[0]){
        const hashedPassword = await pool.query('SELECT password from _user WHERE email = $1',[email])

    
        const compare = await bcrypt.compare(password,hashedPassword.rows[0].password)
        if(compare){
            const userId = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM _user WHERE email = $1',[email])
            return {message:'',data:userId.rows[0].id,success:true}

        }
        else{
            return {message:'Wrong password',data:null, success:false}
        }
   
    }

    else{
        return {message:'Email does not exists in database',data:null,success:false}
    }



}

here is the function for login controller to handle request/response objects:
AuthController.login = async function (req,res){

    try{
    const {data,message,success} = await Auth.login(req.body)
    if(success){
    req.session.sessionId = data
    console.log(req.session)
    return res.status(200).json({message:`user with ID ${data} has logged in successfully`})
    }
    return res.status(400).json({message:message})

    }

    catch(e){
        return res.status(400).json({error:e.message})
    }
}


Also, note how I setup session cookie configuration using express-session in app.js above.
when i try to login with the correct email and password, the session is not stored in browser:

Note that this is how I handle sending a request from client side:
    const handleLoginSubmit = (e)=>{
      e.preventDefault()

      setIsLoading(true)
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/login/',{method:'POST',body:JSON.stringify(loginInfo),headers:{'content-type':'application/json'}}).then((res)=>{
          setIsLoading(false)
            if(res.status == 200){
                route.back()
            }
            if(res.status == 400){
                res.json().then((data)=>{
                    console.log(data)


                    setLoginError(data.message)
                })
            }


    })
  }

Note that I am using 127.0.0.1 host with port 3000 on frontend.
UPDATE
I made few edits, for example I added credintials:'include' here:
   fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/login/',{credentials:'include',method:'POST',body:JSON.stringify(loginInfo),headers:{'content-type':'application/json'}}).then((res)=>{
          setIsLoading(false)
            if(res.status == 200){
                route.back()
            }
            if(res.status == 400){
                res.json().then((data)=>{
                    console.log(data)


                    setLoginError(data.message)
                })
            }


    })
  }

and I made an edit in app.js:
app.use(session(
  {
  store: new pgSessionStore({
    pool:pool,
    tableName:'session',
    createTableIfMissing:true
    
  }),
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
  resave: true,
  cookie: { maxAge: 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,httpOnly: true , domain:'127.0.0.1',secure:false},
  saveUninitialized: true,
}))

i fixed the domain prop to be set to the host without the port
plus, I added secure:false to cookie prop just in case.
As a result, I got this, on logging in:

However, when I reload the login page, the form still appear (as in I still have to log in and not yet authenticated), and the backend is giving me logs that I am not authenticated yet.

I believe you need to set credentials:"include" in your request if you want cookies to be allowed

@JaromandaX I made an update to my post, please check it out

Is the cookie now set in the browser?

"However, when I reload the login page" - that triggers what exactly, on the server side? AuthController.login?

@JaromandaX Yes apparently from screenshot

@C3roe That triggers AuthController.isAuthenticated, which checks if req.session.sessionId exists or not and based on that it would return status 200, or 401

Oh, sorry, I don't look at pictures
